# Bind9 not doing anything with forwarded query responses?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a Bind DNS server that is the local production DNS server and a Windows 2008 R2 domain controller which provides DNS for a lab environment with the domain xyz.lab.  I've configured the Bind DNS to forward DNS requests for the domain xyz.lab to the Windows DNS server with this config:

> zone "xyz.lab" {
> type forward;
> forward only;
> forwarders { x.x.x.x; };
> };
>
> zone "x.x.x.in-addr.arpa" {
> type forward;
> forward only;
> forwarders { x.x.x.x; };
> };

And Bind options are (the all_internal acl includes the subnets of both the production and lab networks as well as the loopback of the bind server):

> allow-query { all_internal; };
> allow-recursion { all_internal; };
> allow-transfer { none; };
> notify no;
> minimal-responses yes;
> version "unknown";

Unfortunately, when I do an nslookup or dig on the bind server for a host on the lab domain, the request times out.  The logs on the Windows 2008 DNS server show it receiving the query and responding to it and a network packet trace shows the query responses arriving at the Bind DNS server.

The servers reside on the same switch with a router providing connectivity between the layer 3 subnets (production and lab are on different subnets) and there is a round trip time of between 3ms and 5ms on pings between the two servers, so I don't think there is an issue with latency causing a timeout of the query.

In summary a query-response arrives back at the Bind server and the nslookup/dig times-out.  Why does the Bind DNS not seem to be doing anything with the query responses when it receives them?

Comment: when you query bind for something else besides the forwarded zone, do you get the reply ?

Comment: which version of Bind are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Bind just ignore some RR with _ try this option : "check-names ignore;"